# File upload progress checking if file send as FormData in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, file-upload, multipartform-data, angular7, form-data

I uploading file as FormData in Angular 7 with this code using `HttpClient` as `http`:

```
sendImageFile(subUri: string, id: number, fileToUpload: File): Observable<any> {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
  formData.append('photoalbum_id', id.toString() );
  // ... some other .append()

  const customHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
    'Accepted-Encoding': 'application/json'
  });

  const customOptions = {
    headers: customHeaders,
    reportProgress: true
  };

  return this.http.post(this.url, formData, customOptions)
    .pipe(
      map( (event: HttpEvent<any>) => this.getEventMessage(event, fileToUpload)),
      tap(message => this.showProgress(message)),
      // last(),
      catchError(this.handleError));
}

private showProgress(message: any) {
  // ...
}

private getEventMessage(event: HttpEvent<any>, file: File) {
  // ...
}
```

The main problem is here isn't checking the uploading because the file is uploaded part of the `FormData` so I don't get any feedback until the upload is finished.

I'm a little bit confused about this progress checking. I must to upload file as FormData. How can I check the upload progress in this case?

Comment: You want to display the percentage of file uploaded while it is being uploaded? and complete message after it is uploaded?

Comment: @Amir: yes, exactly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer lies in `HttpClient`'s implementation. All requests created via the `HttpClient.post` method default the `observe` property to `body`. See [this HttpClient.post method for details](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.0/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L1566). What this means is: even though you successfully set `reportProgress` to `true`, the resulting observable is observing the request body instead of the `HttpEvents`. From [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request) (emphasis mine):

> The observe value determines the return type of request(), based on what the consumer is interested in observing. **A value of events will return an `Observable<HttpEvent>` representing the raw HttpEvent stream**, including progress events by default. A value of response will return an `Observable<HttpResponse<T>>` where the T parameter of HttpResponse depends on the responseType and any optionally provided type parameter. **A value of body will return an `Observable<T>` with the same T body type**.

The documentation also notes that if you pass an `HttpRequest` instance to `request`, it will return an observable of the `HttpEvent` stream by default:

> This method can be called in one of two ways. Either an HttpRequest instance can be passed directly as the only parameter, or a method can be passed as the first parameter, a string URL as the second, and an options hash as the third.
>
> If a HttpRequest object is passed directly, an Observable of the raw HttpEvent stream will be returned.

So, the easiest way to observe the `HttpEvent` stream is to pass an `HttpRequest` object directly as noted:

```js
sendImageFile(subUri: string, id: number, fileToUpload: File): Observable<any> {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
  formData.append('photoalbum_id', id.toString());
  // ... some other .append()

  const customHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
    'Accepted-Encoding': 'application/json'
  });

  const customOptions = {
    headers: customHeaders,
    reportProgress: true,
  };

  const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.url, formData, customOptions);

  // Call HttpClient.request with an HttpRequest as only param to get an observable of HttpEvents
  return this.http.request(req)
    .pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => this.getEventMessage(event)),
      catchError(this.handleError));
}

private getEventMessage(event: HttpEvent<any>) {
  // We are now getting events and can do whatever we want with them!
  console.log(event);
}
```

I tested this refactored code on a local repository and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer!

Comment: NP; glad I could help!

Comment: Some how this example was not completely working for me until I added an additional parameter to `map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => this.getEventMessage(event)),` like this  `map((event: HttpEvent<any>, count: number) => this.getEventMessage(event, count)),` then mixed it up with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54062875/2155645

Answer (score 4):

**EDITED :**
Due to the fact that Angular grows , as I proposed in my previous answer - the npm package would not suit your needs. So here is what you can actually do :

```
private getEventMessage(event: HttpEvent<any>, file: File) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case HttpEventType.Sent:
      return `Uploading file "${file.name}" of size ${file.size}.`;

    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
      // Compute and show the % done:
      const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      return `File "${file.name}" is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`;

    case HttpEventType.Response:
      return `File "${file.name}" was completely uploaded!`;

    default:
      return `File "${file.name}" surprising upload event: ${event.type}.`;
  }
}
```

and then you can  modify your showProgress() function according to the returned values of getEventMessage() . Does this help ?

Comment: looking good, but this project's github repo say "[DEPRECATED] Use @angular/common/http instead"

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't answer to my question. Your code is from the official Angular documentation, what I read and not working in my case because the `getEventMessage()` function wait a `file: File` parameter, but the uploading is happening with a `formData: FormData` variable what contains other things too.